# Is this the best options to create a method that accepts a collection of any type?

Tags: java, generics, collections

I had implemented a method that accepts a Collections of any type as an input. Is there a better solution?

I'm using generics to solve this problem;

My solution uses this as a parameter `(Collection<T> list)`

I'm not sure if there is a better option. Is there a better option?, is my solution a good option?

This is my code:

```
public static <T> boolean doTask(Collection<T> list){
    if(list == null)
        return false;
    else if(list.isEmpty()) return false;
    /* more code*/
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Why have the items implement Comparable? And I don't think the "more code" will ever be executed, nor will it compile.

Comment: Totally agree, let me fix it

Comment: It really depends on what you hide behind "more code". But the code clearly doesn't match your description: not all types extend Comparable, and you're supposed to accept collections of any type. The code also doesn't seem to use the generic type T anywhere, so why is the method generic?

Comment: Ok, I should use the method just like this: public static <T> boolean doTask(Collection<T> list){...}

Comment: Shouldn't it be `containsElements() ` considering it returns false when empty?

Comment: yes, returns false when is null or empty

Comment: Again, why make it generic? You know about wildcars, so why don't you use them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't care about the elements' type at all, you can just use `?` for type.

```
static boolean containsElements(Collection<?> list) {
    return list != null && !list.isEmpty();
}
```

`list.isEmpty()` will not be evaluated when `list` is `null` because the term is already false, so it won't run into an exception.